# Is there a way to raise SNOW ticket as notification for query failures in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, servicenow-rest-api

I was going through the integration documents available for snowflake & service now. But, all documents are oddly focussed on sf consuming snow data for analytics. Didn't find anything related to creating tickets for failures at snowflake. Is it possible?

It's not about the monitoring & notification aspect of snowflake but connecting with service now and raise a ticket for query failures (tasks,sp etc.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Just be careful of your failure raising thousands of tickets when a thousand records fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no functionality like that as of now. I can recommend you open an [Idea](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Search-Create-Vote-Follow-Ideas) for it and if enough customers want it our Product Management will review it.

Answer (score 1):

For the Snowpipe, we found a way to use it. We send the error message to SNS and then we can do a Lambda function to call the Rest API of ServiceNow to create a ticket.

For Task, we find that it is possible to use External Functions to notify to AWS whenever the Task fails, but we haven’t implemented it.

Comment: Thanks @Minh-Long Luu this really helps. I will try to implement

Answer (score 0):

Email is a simple way. You need to determine how your ServiceNow instance is processing emails. We implemented incident creation from Azure App Insights based on emails.

In ServiceNow find the **Inbound Action** you need to process the email or make one.
ServiceNow provides every instance with an email account
Refer to [enter link description here](https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=5c61720c1be260100b8a9979b04bcb4a)

> The instance email is usually xxxx@service-now.com.
> If your instance url is "audi.service-now.com", the email would be "audi@service-now.com".

> For a PDI dev@servicenowdevelopers.com, e.g.; dev12345@servicenowdevelopers.com